# Download file from Google Cloud Storage via PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to download files from my bucket in Google Cloud Storage using PHP. I can upload well. I've tried some codes I've found here but Laravel tells me that class `Google_Http_Request` is not found.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
$request = new Google_Http_Request($object['mediaLink'], 'GET');
$signed_request = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
$http_request = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($signed_request);
echo $http_request->getResponseBody();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to download an object using the latest version of the [client library (v2.0)](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client):

```
// Authenticate your API Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Storage::DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

try {
    // Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of objects in your project.
    $object = $storage->objects->get($bucketName, $objectName);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    // The bucket doesn't exist!
    if ($e->getCode() == 404) {
        exit(sprintf("Invalid bucket or object names (\"%s\", \"%s\")\n", $bucketName, $objectName));
    }
    throw $e;
}

// build the download URL
$uri = sprintf('https://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s?alt=media&generation=%s', $bucketName, $objectName, $object->generation);
$http = $client->authorize();
$response = $http->get($uri);

if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
    exit('download failed!' . $response->getBody());
}

// write the file (or do whatever you'd like with it)
file_put_contents($downloadName, $response->getBody());
```

You can find other samples on using the storage API in this [Samples Repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/api)

There is also a newer library being developed called [gcloud-php](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-php) which has some [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-php/#/) on calling Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: I was using some code examples from an old library. Your code works great! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a sample on how you're uploading? This is my problem at the moment.